# AES Encryption/decryption using Spring Security

Tags: encryption, spring-security, aes

I've been looking all over the internet on how to encrypt/decrypt a password or a String using AES in Spring Framework. Any links or tutorials? Explaining AES is good too but please use a non-nerd words.

If you're wondering why should I do this is because we need to encrypt the password and save it in the session and get it from the session to decrypt then use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords. Hash them. Whenever you need to verify a password, hash the new password and compare the hashes. To make this more secure use something like PBKDF2 or scrypt with a salt and a lot of iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring security actually does not build encryption tools themselves - they deal more with authentication, login, sessions, and encoding (so, hashing passwords and that sort of thing). Take a look at http://www.jasypt.org/, which is commonly used with spring security if encryption/decryption is needed at the spring security level (http://www.jasypt.org/springsecurity.html).